# Problem trying to make two child processes share the load of processing the same resource

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm messing around with python multiprocessing module. But something is not working as I was expecting it to do, so now I'm a little bit confused.

In a python script, I create two child processes, so they can work with the same resource. I was thinking that they were going to "share" the load more or less equally, but it seems that, instead of doing that, one of the processes executes just once, while the other one process almost everything.

To test it, I wrote the following code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import multiprocessing

# Worker function
def worker(queueA, queueB):
    while(queueA.qsize() != 0):
        item = queueA.get()
        item = "item: " + item + ". processed by worker " + str(os.getpid())
        queueB.put(item)
    return

# IPC Manager
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
queueA = multiprocessing.Queue()
queueB = multiprocessing.Queue()

# Fill queueA with data
for i in range(0, 10):
    queueA.put("hello" + str(i+1))

# Create processes
process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (queueA, queueB,))
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (queueA, queueB,))

# Call processes
process1.start()
process2.start()

# Wait for processes to stop processing
process1.join()
process2.join()

for i in range(0, queueB.qsize()):
    print queueB.get()
```

And that prints the following:

```
item: hello1. processed by worker 11483
item: hello3. processed by worker 11483
item: hello4. processed by worker 11483
item: hello5. processed by worker 11483
item: hello6. processed by worker 11483
item: hello7. processed by worker 11483
item: hello8. processed by worker 11483
item: hello9. processed by worker 11483
item: hello10. processed by worker 11483
item: hello2. processed by worker 11482
```

As you can see, one of the processes works with just one of the elements, and it doesn't continue to get more elements of the queue, while the other has to work with everything else.

I'm thinking that this is not correct, or at least not what I expected. Could you tell me which is the correct way of implementing this idea?

Comment: If my answer cleared things up please mark it accepted, if you still have concerns please let me know and I will try to address them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that they won't be exactly equal, but mostly that's because your testing sample is so small.  It takes time for each process to get started and start processing.  The time it takes to process an item in the queue is extremely low and therefore one can quickly process 9 items before the other gets through one.

I tested this below (in Python3, but it should apply for 2.7 as well just change the `print()` function to a `print` statement):

```py
import os
import multiprocessing

# Worker function
def worker(queueA, queueB):
    for item in iter(queueA.get, 'STOP'):
        out = str(os.getpid())
        queueB.put(out)
    return

# IPC Manager
manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
queueA = multiprocessing.Queue()
queueB = multiprocessing.Queue()

# Fill queueA with data
for i in range(0, 1000):
    queueA.put("hello" + str(i+1))

# Create processes
process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (queueA, queueB,))
process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target = worker, args = (queueA, queueB,))

# Call processes
process1.start()
process2.start()

queueA.put('STOP')
queueA.put('STOP')

# Wait for processes to stop processing
process1.join()
process2.join()

all = {}
for i in range(1000):
    item = queueB.get()
    if item not in all:
        all[item] = 1
    else:
        all[item] += 1
print(all)
```

My output (a count of how many were done from each process):

```
{'18376': 537, 
 '18377': 463}
```

While they aren't the exact same, as we approach longer times they will approach being about equal.

**Edit:**
Another way to confirm this is to add a `time.sleep(3)` inside the worker function

```py
def worker(queueA, queueB):
    for item in iter(queueA.get, 'STOP'):
        time.sleep(3)
        out = str(os.getpid())
        queueB.put(out)
    return
```

I ran a `range(10)` test like in your original example and got:

```
{'18428': 5,
 '18429': 5}
```

Comment: Thank you, GiraffeMan91! Your answer did clear up my doubts, I wasn't having that "starting time" in mind. 

Also, sorry for the delay! I'm working in an assignment for university, and you saved me a lot of time of googling and trying to figure out what was happening. Greets :)

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to make sure you saw the answer. Lots of people ask questions and never return or mark them answered. Glad it helped clear it up :)